# Passing params to POST API

Tags: api, rest

I am new to designing REST APIs. I have trying to create following APIs for online game play

```
GET domain/api/games // return all games
POST domain/api/games // create a new game on behalf of current user
```

Now my issue is that when I try to create game using POST, I want userId to be sent to the API. I am not sure how to do this. Also note that I have another get API to get details of individual game, something like

```
GET domain/api/games/{gameId}
```

so I cannot pass userId to POST like domain/api/games/{useID} as it will conflict will above API. 
So how do I pass usedId to POST. Also I don't want to use query params. Any suggestions to design this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are making a POST to a service, the parameters you communicate are known as BODY params, they don't go on the query string.

Different technologies have different APIs for interacting with POST params, but the underlying theory is the same, and is described by the W3C HTTP standard

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

The specifics of how to use POST params vary depending on the language and technology you're using. For example, if you are using jquery, there are a couple different ways to do it, with with the $.post('url', data, callback) method or with the $.ajax(...) option.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

When reading POST params on the server, you'll generally access them using some some sort of request object, that will store your parameters in memory for you to access. This is highly dependent of the language and framework you're using, but here are links to some common ones:

NodeJS/express: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#request

PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

ASP.Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx

Java/Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: I am using Java, so as per your suggestion I can use a form post to my POST API and handle form data containing usedId in my backend logic. right?

Comment: You'll most likely want to use an ajax request rather than a standard form POST. If you just use <form method="POST" action="..."> then your web application will display the results of the API call to the user, not a web page. You'll want to use some sort of ajax request to send the data to your api, and then get the response code back and update the UI dynamically. I can't think of any situation where you'd want to use a standard html POST to an API.

Answer (score 0):

It should be either part of the context (you can pass it through header) or part of the game object. I prefer the context option, the httpheader can contain some auth bearer token so that you can figure out the user on the backend through the token.